# Can't convert text to numeric

Tags: r, text, numeric

I've downloaded the information about energy outages, from a text file. This is what the data looks like, in my R environment:

```
 bairro            consumidores dec       ano
  <chr>             <chr>        <chr>   <dbl>
1 AGUA GRANDE        44.417       5,68    2017
2 ALDEIA CAMPISTA    38.589       3,42    2017
3 ALVORADA           27.660       2,74    2017
4 AREIA BRANCA       124.193      7,29    2017
5 ARI FRANCO         65.563       9,79    2017
6 BAEPENDI           11.056       12,09   2017
```

However, I can't merge this table with another that I have and also I can't convert the dec column to numeric.

Comment: Could you provide the code you've used to read the data

Comment: what "NA" error? Can you add a bit more explanation? What are you copying to excel? That link is just blank for me. How are you reading it into R? And how are you converting to numeric? Do you mean converting each individual column to numeric? if so please include your code

Comment: @NelsonGon, I did some changes in my question.

Comment: @RAB,  I did some changes in my question.

Comment: Run `Sys.localeconv()` to verify whether the "." or "," is the decimal separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is called `df`:

```
df$dec <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", df$dec))
```